# Units and attribute changes with minimal code

Tags: java, methods

I am still learning Java and have a VERY BASIC knowledge about the programming language. I'm looking to create a simple Java game where I have a few units, friendly and foe, that each have a number of attributes which I want to be able to change based on abilities that each unit has. These are my unit types so far; Medic, Officer, Ranger, Small Enemy, and Big Enemy, all of these are classes. Each unit will have the following attributes:

```
static int health = 1000;
static int power = 100;
static int moves = 6;
static int movement = 8;
```

I believe the attribute changes I am seeking can be achieved through calling methods however, I want to create one modular method that can simply target a unit and affect a change. Here is an example of what I want to do based on a medic ability:

```
public static void Heal() {
    Medic.moves = Medic.moves - 2;
    (target).health = (target).health + 200;
}
```

In the above example I am not sure how to achieve the "target" functionality. This is basically the crux of my question, how could I create this method to be modular so that I don't have to write a method that specifically states the name of the target within the method like below?

```
public static void Heal() {
    Medic.moves = Medic.moves - 2;
    Ranger.health = Ranger.health + 200;
}

public static void Heal() {
    Medic.moves = Medic.moves - 2;
    Officer.health = Officer.health + 200;
}

public static void Heal() {
    Medic.moves = Medic.moves - 2;
    Medic.health = Medic.health + 200;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Pass the unit as a parameter: `public void heal( Unit unit ) { unit.addHealth( 200 );  moves -= 2;}`  Note that `static` is a very bad idea based on your problem description and you should probably drop all of the uses of `static` in your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please read (and follow) the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an abstract class `Unit` with your attributes (but you should NOT use static at all).

Create concrete class for each kind of Unit.

Create methods allowing to perform the action, like `Heal()`.

For instance:

```
public abstract class Unit {
  private int health;
  private int power;
  private int moves;
  private int movement;

    protected Unit(int health, int power, int moves, int movement) {
      health = health;
      power = power;
      moves = moves;
      movement = movement;
    }

}

public class Medic extends Unit {

    public Medic() {
      super(1000, 100, 6, 8);
    } 

    public Medic(int health, int power, int moves, int movement) {
      super(health, power, moves, movement);
    }

    public void Heal(Unit target) {
      moves -= 2;
      target.health += 200;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply create all your units with concrete type (you may implement additional constructors allowing to specify various attributes' values) and then call the methods on your instances.

Comment: I would argue that `Medic` ought to be a subclass of `Unit`, and that only the `Medic` class should have a `heal` method. (Also... no maximum unit health?)

Comment: I agree with you (the fact is I m on a smartphone in a train... Not easy to write ) and I updated my answer consequently.

Comment: I get what you are saying here but, how do I assign each of my unit types to this? I would want each unit type to have a specific set of attributes. Essentially, how do I create instances of Medic, Ranger, and so on in such a way that I can give them each their own attribute set based on the class attributes?

Comment: Bsquare, is there a term for passing in specifically the parameters "Unit target"? I'm trying to look into this again and I want to understand how this works as I have experimented with changing the parameters but have not found anything that works besides the "Unit target" combination.

Comment: What do you mean by 'a term'? Let's say you want a medic to heal another one, you may have something like `Medic medic1 = new Medic(); Medic medic2 = new Medic();`, then `medic2` can heal ``medic1` this way: `medic2.Heal(medic1)`

Answer (score -1):

You should pass the unit as a parameter to your method, and all of your units should be children of a parent class. If we name the parent class `Unit`, it should look something like this (since the attributes for all the units are the same):

```
public class Unit {
private int health = 1000;
private int power = 100;
private int moves = 6;
private int movement = 8;
//getters and setters
}
```

So now your method will look something like this:

```
public void Heal(Unit unit) {
    Medic.moves = Medic.moves - 2;
    unit.setHealth(unit.getHealth + 200);
}
```